# Error Handling within Python AddIns?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, error-000725

I'm working on some code for a toolbar I made using Python-addin that makes buildings. Part of the code that does this makes a Temporary table view. If my code attempts to make that table view again when it already exists, this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "filepath", line error happens on, in onClick
    '')
  File "otherfilepath", line I didn't code, in MakeTableView
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000725: Table Name: Dataset editViewStormBill already exists.
Failed to execute (MakeTableView).
```

I've already made changes in my code to ensure that this error isn't thrown every time a building is drawn. This error is only thrown right now if the user takes a specific action that shows they don't really understand how the toolbar works. What I would like to do is catch the error with an exception that prints out a few lines explaining what the user did wrong and then pass over that part of the code so the rest of the code can attempt to run. I've done this before, but I don't know what to call the error in the try except statement. Here is the bit I'm struggling with:

```
if button2.isTableView == False:
                try:
                    tableView = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc,
                                                "editView" + str(button2.i),
                                               "",workspace,
                                               '')
                    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management((tableView),"TRANSACTIONAL",
                                                       button2.currentVersion,
                                                       '')
                    button2.isTableView = True
                except ???:#What goes here?
                    pass
```

So far I have tried putting ExecuteError where the questions marks are and nothing happens. What do I put after except; what part of the error tells me what to write for my exception in python?

I'm not overwriting output because that approach would have my code make the tableView every time this button is pressed which would make the toolbar slower and less useful.

If you need to reproduce this error in order to explain how to read error messages then do this:

```
                try:
                    tableView = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc,
                                                "editView",
                                               "",workspace,
                                               '')
                    tableView = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc,
                                                "editView",
                                               "",workspace,
                                               '')
                    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management((tableView),"TRANSACTIONAL",
                                                       button2.currentVersion,
                                                       '')
                    button2.isTableView = True
                except :#What goes here?
                    pass
```

Comment: I think this is a raw python question, not directly GIS related, and would be best asked on [SO]

Comment: @Midavalo it's more pythony than it is GIS-y, but python exceptions generally don't work this way from what I've seen. I'm fairly certain that people who don't work with arcpy won't be able to answer this. I need to mention python-addin in this question.

Comment: Some suggestions - `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`, `if arcpy.exists(tableView.getOutput(0))`, or a catch all try/except **only** around the MakeTableView call `try:` `except Exception as e:`

Comment: I think we need a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck.  I would try to abstract the problem away from a versioned geodatabase into a file geodatabase so that your chances of finding a potential answerer willing to volunteer the testing time will increase.  The code snippet should be a whole simple Python AddIn including the script and config.xml.

Comment: @PolyGeo This question isn't about the specific error. It's about reading esri error messages. i should edit it to make that more clear

Comment: I've voted to close this for lacking a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that works up to where you are stuck, but I could just as easily have voted for it to be closed as too broad.  By working on how to solve one specific instance you may well find the more generic answer that you seek.

Comment: @PolyGeo it's always nice to know you refuse to stop following me around this website. I'm pretty sure you've edited all my questions but one.

Comment: @Luke The arcpy.Exists method doesn't work because it has to reference the variable before it is created.

Comment: If you are asking ArcPy questions then I suspect that I will have looked at all your questions, and will continue to try to help you improve them so that they can be answered clearly and more quickly.  Python AddIn questions are more difficult to present code snippets for than other ArcPy questions but doing so is no less valuable for both askers and potential answerers.

Comment: @luke Your exception suggestion hit the nail right on the head. I'll be happy to give you points for answering if you put that with a brief explanation of why it's correct in an answer to this question. Also you have to convince PolyGeo to open the question. Sorry

Comment: @PolyGeo open my question Luke answered it correctly in the comments. He deserves his points!

Comment: Also I would like to formally request that Poly Geo stop modding my posts. I'll take literally any other mod. I'll take two other mods at once even.

Comment: Damn those nasty moderators, snooping around the site trying to make it better!

Comment: I'll re-open so you can answer @Luke - there was insufficient detail to interest me in spending enough time to try and test but I'm glad you were able to understand the issue with less.

Comment: Just sticking my oar in to say that a plain `except:` would actually work, but is too blunt a tool to be used in most situations. `except arcpy.ExecuteError:` is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid `ERROR 000725: Table Name: Dataset editViewStormBill already exists.` by setting `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Otherwise you can use `arcpy.ExecuteError` to catch the exception and arcpy.GetMessages() to print it out.

```
import arcpy, pythonaddins
#Stuff...

try:
    tableView = arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc,
        "editView" + str(button2.i), 
        workspace=workspace).getOutput(0)
    arcpy.ChangeVersion_management((tableView),"TRANSACTIONAL",
        button2.currentVersion)
    button2.isTableView = True

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    #print arcpy.GetMessages()
    pythonaddins.MessageBox(arcpy.GetMessages(), 'Oh dear, you messed up...')
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `print "stuff"` would print stuff to the python window in arcmaps

Comment: It's `arcpy.ExecuteError`

Comment: @Steve there's also pythonaddins.MessageBox http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/the-pythonaddins-module.htm